# gson exclusion strategy apply only to fields of target object

Tags: java, serialization, gson, field

I want to prevent Gson from serializing fields of a specific type. For this, I have created an exclusion strategy. The exclusion strategy does successfully recognize when the class in question is being processed and it does successfully exclude it. Unfortunately, it prevents me from serializing objects of that class even when they are the root. By that I mean they are the argument passed to the gson.toJson() method.

To be more clear, I have a class of type Person with class fields that themselves involve the Person type. I do not want to serialize class fields of the type Person.

```
public class Person{
   private Person child;
   private String name;
}
```

So, in the above example, I want a json object containing the `name` field but not the `child` field. I want the solution to be sensitive the the type of the field, not the field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ExclusionStrategy` defines two methods, one to exclude types and one to exclude fields. Just use the field method to skip any fields of type `Person`.

```
class PersonExcluder implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaredType().equals(Person.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then use register it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new PersonExcluder()).create();
```

Comment: I did this. However, when I passed a Person into gson.toJson() it returned null. I assume it is not serializing anything because the object is being excluded, could it be something else?

Comment: Yeah, most likely the value you passed it is null. The above works with 2.3.1.

Comment: So I just stepped through the code to see that the value passed to gson.toJson() is not null. It definately has an instance of an object going in, and coming out is a String with the value: "null". 

However, I noticed thanks to your example that I had put my check in the method "shouldSkipClass" instead of "shouldSkipField". This was a misunderstanding on my part on what class was being passed to "shouldSkipClass".